# Running Ubuntu 12.10 with some issues

Tags: terminal

First, I can't remove a program, Krita, and it seems I have two icons in the apps listing. It states "E:dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure - a' to correct the problem" Well, the problem is that I type that into terminal and it says I don't have superuser access.. I am the only user on this computer.

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Being the only user on the computer doesnt give you superuser/root privileges.  For security and safety, you still need to elevate your access to perform certain tasks.  `dpkg` is one of those tasks, as improper use can break dependencies that programs require, or even render the operating system unusable.

In order to do this, you need to use the `sudo` command to elevate your privileges.

You will need to type:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

You will then be prompted for your password.  Enter it and your command will then run with elevated privileges.

Find more information on `sudo` [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo).

On a side note, why are you using such an old version of Ubuntu?